# How to restore the deleted files on Google api account?

Tags: google-cloud-iam

We applied Google drive's api on our product.

As the system received the information, the same information will be recorded in google spreadsheet at the same time.

We are now having problem that our clients accidentally delete the file.
Is there a way to restore the file in the iam.gserviceaccount?
We've tried to untrash, but it is not working.

The original url of the file:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGLawTZvPs4fvGA4cGwfjySdM9olbdVtMRwm89z5Mm4/edit#gid=0
The account: botbonniedev@psychic-etching-177004.iam.gserviceaccount.com
The delete date and time: Jul 12th, 12:00(GMT+8)

Answer (score 0):

Recover/restore deleted service accounts:
After you delete a service account, IAM permanently removes the service account 30 days later. There is no way to restore a deleted service account that has been permanently removed.

Before 30 days you can recover /restore the accounts below article is helpful.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/undelete

(OR)
Via Gcloud

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/iam/service-accounts/undelete

Comment: Seems the problem is a google sheet file been delete by api account, not account been deleted.

Comment: Hi Lakshmi,
Thank you for answering!
However, our service account is not deleted. 
Is the "spreadsheet file" created by the account was deleted.

Did you have this kind of experience? Or the solution for this.

It will be so much help if you can share with me. Thank you!!

Comment: Please check below article it's helpful.    https://support.google.com/a/thread/116883703/how-to-restore-the-deleted-files-on-google-api-account?hl=en

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6052340?hl=en

Comment: Hi  Chloe Wong ,If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it (✔️). I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!